# Failed to run Mac app after being installed by PackageMaker-based installer, Only fails on multiple user accounts machine

Tags: macos, mono, installation, packagemaker

I have prepared mono app bundle. Then I used Apple's ***PackageMaker*** for making an installer.
The installer has post script which fixes some relative symbolic links inside the bundle folder after being installed in /Applications.

I've tested the installer on a fresh Mac machine with single admin user account. The installer succeeds and the installed application runs perfectly.

The problem is :
When I created another admin account on that machine. The installation succeeded, but the installed bundle's icon has an overly (stop or Blocked) icon!
And when I run my applications, it refuses and the flowing message pops up :

> You can't open the application XYZ because it is not supported on this
>   type of Mac.

I knew it *SHOULD* be supported, as it was working on "this type of mac" !
tried to modify user/group and permissions for the bundle in *PackageMaker* window, but not luck.

Can you please clarify my confusion regarding this message and the suggested solution ?